# If $\langle x,y \rangle$ is not nilpotent, then $\langle xu,yv \rangle$ is not nilpotent for $u,v \in Z^*(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group which is not weakly nilpotent and $Z^*(G)$ be it hypercenter. Let $x,y \in G$ such that $\langle x,y \rangle$ is not nilpotent. Then, is it true that for all $u,v \in Z^*(G)$, $\langle xu,yv \rangle$ is also not nilpotent?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think so. If $\langle xu,yv \rangle$ is nilpotent, then $\langle Z^*(G),xu,yv  \rangle$ is hypercentral, and hence $\langle x,y \rangle$ is nilpotent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if $\langle xu,yv \rangle$ s nilpotent, then $\langle Z^*(G),xu,yv  \rangle$ is hypercentral, and hence $\langle x,y \rangle$ is nilpotent.